# How to share folders in Windows 7 to users on other computers on the network ?

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

Does anyone can tell how to efficiently use sharing in Windows 7 so that for instance: Can I set up sharing on machine A (to a user on machine B) so that a user from machine B can use his own login and password (from machine B) to log in to the machine A and use the shared folders ?

I know it's a bit confusing but the same is sharing folders for me in Windows 7.

Comment: you might want to read this article if they are different versions of Windows...http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Networking-home-computers-running-different-versions-of-Windows

Comment: If they are all Windows 7 PC's...http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/help/home-sweet-homegroup-networking-the-easy-way

Comment: Thanks Moab for these links - I already know about Homegroup but I have encountered a lot of problems with it lately, namely: e.g. I create a Homegroup, use the password to join the Homegroup one another computer on the network but the windows with "Join the Homegroup" just 'works' and nothing happens. I have even tried it the other way and the same happens. Strange...

Comment: MS tried to make networking easier in W7, but I think it backfired! Thought you might learn something new from those links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you just have to make a user account on Machine A to match the user from Machine B. I.E. if Bob37 wants files on Machine A, make an account for Bob37 and put share permissions to everyone, then fr security permissions, make it only accessable to Bob37 and You32 (your account).

As an afterthought, if Bob37 changes his password ever on his Machine B, his password would remain the same on Machine A. If you have a password expiration, he would have to log in locally to machine A every time his password expired. Workgroup sharing is easy as long as you don't get more than a few users.

Comment: I think that would be the only reasonable solution (as long as noone else would come up with better idea)

Comment: "Workgroup sharing is easy as long as you don't get more than a few users."
what do you mean by Workgroup sharing ?

Comment: Oh, there's two types of main computer structures. Workgroup (or peer to peer), and domain (or server to client). I assume you just have two home computers, so you should have workgroup. If you notice under your computer information (right click on "my computer") it will have a workgroup or domain. I think the default is "WORKGROUP". Sharing files on a workgroup is pretty simple, but it's really annoying if you have a ton of users. A server/client (domain) structure makes it much easier to manage users, as you get 'checked in' by a single place, as opposed to each individual computer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't login into a share with a user account other than what resides on the pc hosting the share.  Unless you use windows server and active directory. You can however add the everyone object in your share permissions so that no one needs to log in.

Comment: I wanted to omit that so that not everyone on the network would be able to access these files but only designated people.

Comment: Well regardless of that you still have your answer